# how to fix this error? im using php

Tags: php

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error
```

.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

```
error_log:
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Tue Dec 03 17:09:22.142866 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14156:tid 408] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 03 17:09:22.142866 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14156:tid 408] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Tue Dec 03 17:09:22.142866 2013] [core:notice] [pid 14156:tid 408] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Tue Dec 03 17:09:22.144866 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14156:tid 408] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 14052
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Tue Dec 03 17:09:22.809904 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14052:tid 300] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Dec 03 17:11:22.260736 2013] [core:alert] [pid 14052:tid 1552] [client 127.0.0.1:52157] C:/wamp/www/nmb48/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Tue Dec 03 17:11:28.206076 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14156:tid 408] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Dec 03 17:11:30.214191 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14052:tid 300] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Dec 03 17:11:30.236192 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14156:tid 408] AH00430: Parent: Child process 14052 exited successfully.
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Tue Dec 03 17:11:31.524266 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10180:tid 408] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 03 17:11:31.525266 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10180:tid 408] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Tue Dec 03 17:11:31.525266 2013] [core:notice] [pid 10180:tid 408] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Tue Dec 03 17:11:31.526266 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10180:tid 408] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7664
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Tue Dec 03 17:11:32.229306 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7664:tid 300] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Dec 03 17:12:19.407005 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10180:tid 408] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Dec 03 17:12:21.411119 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7664:tid 300] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Dec 03 17:12:21.434121 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10180:tid 408] AH00430: Parent: Child process 7664 exited successfully.
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Tue Dec 03 17:12:23.036212 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 904:tid 408] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 03 17:12:23.036212 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 904:tid 408] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Tue Dec 03 17:12:23.036212 2013] [core:notice] [pid 904:tid 408] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Tue Dec 03 17:12:23.037212 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 904:tid 408] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9288
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Tue Dec 03 17:12:23.732252 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9288:tid 300] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Dec 03 17:15:00.675229 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 904:tid 408] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Dec 03 17:15:02.683344 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9288:tid 300] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Dec 03 17:15:02.706345 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 904:tid 408] AH00430: Parent: Child process 9288 exited successfully.
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Tue Dec 03 17:15:04.385441 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4544:tid 408] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 03 17:15:04.385441 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4544:tid 408] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Tue Dec 03 17:15:04.385441 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4544:tid 408] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Tue Dec 03 17:15:04.386441 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4544:tid 408] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 11524
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Tue Dec 03 17:15:05.087481 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11524:tid 300] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Dec 03 17:21:07.324200 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4544:tid 408] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Dec 03 17:21:09.328314 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11524:tid 300] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Dec 03 17:21:09.351316 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4544:tid 408] AH00430: Parent: Child process 11524 exited successfully.
```

Comment: you need to check DocumentRoot location in httpd.conf , that is not matching a physical location

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough information for people to be able to reply to "how to fix this error?".
It could be all manner of things, and without info it's impossible to tell.

Did the issue start after you uploaded a file? Perhaps a new .php file, or .htaccess file?
These (and other) file types can cause a server problem, so check what you last uploaded (if anything) and upload a previous version, or better yet back up files you recently added (if any) and remove them from the server, and see if the error goes away.

You need to examine the log files more closely.  Read through and see if you can see anything that looks serious, paste the log entry details into Stack Overflow search (and Google) and see if others have details about it.

You should typically be looking in /var/log/apache2/error.log, but depends on what the config is set to.